# How to migrate from DelayedJob to Sidekiq

Tags: heroku, redis, unicorn, sidekiq

My app was working with DelayedJob but was slow so I decided to switch to Sidekiq.

So far it is not working in test or development with Sidekiq. (Naturally, and I have not tried pushing to production with Sidekiq.)

When moving from DelayedJob to Sidekiq, I started by updating my `Profile`:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
# worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
before_fork do |server, worker|
   @sidekiq_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec sidekiq -c 2")
end
```

I'm assuming this means I do not have to type `bundle exec sidekiq` before `foreman start`, right? And this should start sidekiq when I run my tests too, right?

But in my tests, everything in my app that's expressed as `@instance.delay.method` (as should work with both DelayedJob and Sidekiq) is not working.

So to try to get a handle on what's happening, I added the following to my `routes.rb`:

```
Testivate::Application.routes.draw do
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq"
```

But when I restart and visit `localhost:3000/sidekiq` I just see:

```
No route matches [GET] "/sidekiq"
Routes
Routes match in priority from top to bottom
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          
sidekiq_web_path         /sidekiq    Sidekiq::Web
```

BTW, redis appears to be running locally automatically:

```
$ redis-cli ping
PONG
```

And my bundled `gemfile` includes:

```
ruby "2.0.0"
gem "rails", "4.0.2"
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
gem "sidekiq"
gem "autoscaler"
```

I haven't made any changes to `unicorn.rb`:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes 3
timeout 360
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved from DJ to Sidekiq myself. Though I don't see anything obvious in your configs, I'll share my setup that's working.  A few suggestions on how your configuring Sidekiq. Hope this helps.

For initializers/redis.rb, support both local and heroku envs:

```
module MyRedis
  class << self
      def redis
        @redis ||= Redis.new(url: (ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'))
      end

      ##
      # test for avail
      #         
      def sidekiq?
       begin
        redis_info = Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.info }
        true
       rescue
        false
       end
      end
   end
end
```

For initilizers/sidekiq.rb (consider parameterizing `size`)

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => MyRedis.redis[:url], :namespace => 'sidekiq', :size => 4 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => MyRedis.redis[:url], :namespace => 'sidekiq', :size => 1 }
end
```

A typical config/sidekiq.yml:

```
:verbose: false
:concurrency:  25
:queues:
 - [often, 7]
 - [default, 5]
 - [seldom, 3]
```

Then in your Procfile, sidekiq.yml:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RAILS_ENV -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e $RAILS_ENV
```

Lastly, the only changes I made to config/unicorn.rb is to handle redis connection on forking:

```
 ...
 before_fork do |server, worker|

   if defined?(MyRedis.redis)
     MyRedis.redis.quit
     Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')
   end 


 ...
 after_fork do |server, worker|

   if defined?(MyRedis.redis)
     MyRedis.redis.client.reconnect
     Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
   end
```

Comment: 4 Redis connections shared by 25 threads is way too low.  Lower the concurrency to 6-8 or raise the server pool size in the initializer to 15 or more.  Connection pools are lazy so it will only create as many connections as it actually needs at runtime.